# how can add auto watermark script in my news site?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a news site with php & mysql

how can i add a script to auto watermark my news images?

this code is my site news connection to mysql :

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT newsid,title,img,stext,ltext,count,date,time,source FROM news WHERE newsid='$newsid' AND cat <> '1' LIMIT 1");
```

"img" is my news image file

How can i add an image watermark on "img" file?

Comment: You have the image data in the database, or some kind of path to the file?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: @complex857:i image data store in database : column name is "img"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  [**GD**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) in PHP to create text watermark. The following code uses [**PDO**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)
in place of deprecated `mysql_`functions. The watermark is added to a .png file. If other file type is used you will require to change `imagecreatefrompng()` and header to suit.If the image is stored as `blob`(Not recommended) use `imagecreatefromstring()` and the header relevant to the file type of image.

```
<?php
function ImageStringCenter($image, $fontSize, $lineNumber, $totalLines, $text, $color ) { 
    $centerX = ceil( ( imagesx($image) - ( ImageFontWidth($fontSize) * strlen($text) ) ) / 2 ); 
    $centerY = ceil( ( ( imagesy($image) - ( ImageFontHeight($fontSize) * $totalLines ) ) / 2)  + ( ($lineNumber-1) * ImageFontHeight($fontSize) ) ); 
    ImageString($image, $fontSize, $centerX, $centerY, $text, $color ); 
} 
require("dbinfo.php");//database connection paramerters 
$id = 1;
//Connect to database
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
try {
    // Prepare statement
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM images WHERE id = ?");
    // Assign parameters
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$id);
    //Execute query
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->execute();
    // Fetch Result
    $result = $stmt -> fetch();
    $image1 = $result["image2"];
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($image1);//for .png file
    $text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 266, 266, 266);
    ImageStringCenter($im, 5, 1, 2,  "Watermark", $text_color);
    ImageStringCenter($im, 5, 2, 2,  "20/02/2013", $text_color);
    header("Content-Type: image/png");//for .png file
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($image1);
}


catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "The following error occured.". $e->getMessage() ;// Remove or modify after testing 
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt',date('[Y-m-d H:i:s]').", mapSelect.php, ". $e->getMessage()."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);  
 }
//Close the connection
$dbh = null; 
?>
```

**Sample watermark**
[image: Sample watermark]

Answer (score 0):

You could use GD or imageMagick

For example:
http://permadi.com/blog/2010/03/using-php-gd-to-add-watermark-to-images/

(code from link above)

```
01  <?php
02     // Load the image where the logo will be embeded into
03     $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_GET['imageURL']);
04   
05   
06     // Load the logo image
07     $logoImage = imagecreatefrompng("logo.png");
08     imagealphablending($logoImage, true);
09        
10     // Get dimensions
11     $imageWidth=imagesx($image);
12     $imageHeight=imagesy($image);
13        
14     $logoWidth=imagesx($logoImage);
15     $logoHeight=imagesy($logoImage);    
16        
17     // Paste the logo
18     imagecopy(
19        // destination
20        $image,
21        // source
22        $logoImage,
23        // destination x and y
24        $imageWidth-$logoWidth, $imageHeight-$logoHeight,   
25        // source x and y
26        0, 0,
27        // width and height of the area of the source to copy
28        $logoWidth, $logoHeight);
29           
30     // Set type of image and send the output
31     header("Content-type: image/png");
32     imagePng($image);
33    
34     // Release memory
35     imageDestroy($image);
36     imageDestroy($imageLogo);    
37  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will require images to be stored as files on the server.

First, load CodeIgniter's image library if it's not already autoloaded.

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');
```

The following will add a watermark at the bottom of your image in the center.

```
$config['source_image'] = '/path/to/image.jpg';
$config['wm_text'] = 'Your watermark text';
$config['wm_type'] = 'text';
$config['wm_font_path'] = './system/fonts/texb.ttf';
$config['wm_font_size'] = '16';
$config['wm_font_color'] = 'ffffff';
$config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
$config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
$config['wm_padding'] = '20';

$this->image_lib->initialize($config); 

$this->image_lib->watermark();
```

If you want an image as a watermark instead, change

```
$config['wm_text'] = 'Your watermark text';
$config['wm_type'] = 'text';
```

to

```
$config['wm_overlay_path'] = '/path/to/overlay.png';
$config['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
```